# Unable to change permissions on file

Tags: windows, permissions, vmware, windows-server-2012, vmdk

I've mounted a VMDK using VMware Workstation on a Windows Server 2012 box and I'm unable to change permissions on any of the files.

This is preventing me from copying the file and from attaching it within SQL server.

If I try to change the owner of any files or change any of the NTFS permissions I get the following error:

"Can't open access control editor. Unable to perform a security operation on an object that has no associated security."

I've also tried to use the command line to take ownership but get the following error:

"ERROR: File ownership cannot be applied on insecure file systems; there is no support for ACLs."

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What OS is running in the VM?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by running VMware Workstation as an admin before mounting the VMDK.

I then had to run notepad as an admin and use the file browser within there to see the mapped drive and perform the security changes.